# QStatusBar message disappears on menu hover

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4

I have a very basic `QMainWindow` application that contains a `menubar` and a `statusbar`. When I hover over the menu the status message disappears. More precisely, the status message is cleared. I have no idea what is causing this behavior but it's resulting in a very difficult workaround for what I hoped to be trivial behavior.

This is problematic for the following reason:
I can make the message permanent by adding a `QLabel` widget to the `QStatusBar`, but then I get the awkward border. I don't want the border. The only way I know how to remove the border is via `QStatusBar.setStyleSheet()`. I am using a palette for my color scheme as opposed to a stylesheet so modifying the stylesheet messes up other colors. I also can't restore the original `statusBar QLabel` color when I make a modification via the stylesheet. I'm not the best at using stylesheets.

Is there a way to prevent the menu interaction from clearing the status message? If not, is there a way to remove the border from the StatusBar when adding a QLabel widget while preserving my palette (maybe not via stylesheets)?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(win,self).__init__(parent)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.fileMenu  = QMenu("File")
        self.exitAction = QAction("Exit",self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAction)
        self.menubar.addMenu(self.fileMenu)   
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Hello")
        self.connect(self.exitAction,SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.close)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = win()
    GUI.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, each widget you hover over sets the status bar text to their `statusTip` property even when that property is an empty string.

For `QMenu`, the text is stored in the `menuAction` action status tip, so, you can have a text instead of just clearing the status bar with something like this:

```
self.fileMenu.menuAction().setStatusTip("File Menu is hovered")
```

To prevent anything to change the status bar, you can probably install an `eventFilter` on the status bar and filter out all `QStatusTipEvent`.

Comment: Is this specific to QMainWindows? I did not notice this behavior when I used a status bar with a QDialog. I didn't have a menu so maybe that's why.

Comment: @user1054424 Yes, it is specific. The `QStatusTipEvent` is sent even for hovered widgets in a `QDialog` but it isn't handled by anything by default.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem, and I found another way which is creating a new QLabel

```
self.myMessage = QtGui.QLabel()
self.myMessage.setText("Hello")
```

and add it as an widget to the status bar on the left

```
self.statusBar.addWidget(self.myMessage)
```

or on the right

```
self.statusBar.addPermanentWidget(self.myMessage)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to update Lazywii's answer regarding using a QLabel. That code didn't work exactly as is so maybe there have been some changes since 2016 but what did work in 2020 on PyQt5 is:

```
    self.myMessage = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.myMessage.setText("My message not affected by tooltips from hovering")

    self.statusbar.addWidget(self.myMessage)
```

Answer (score 3):

### One complete example

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/2/15 22:27
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class StatusTipFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, watched: QtCore.QObject, event: QtCore.QEvent) -> bool:
        if isinstance(event, QtGui.QStatusTipEvent):
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(watched, event)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window.menuBar().addMenu("File")
window.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")
window.menuBar().installEventFilter(StatusTipFilter(window))
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

And to answer the portion about removing the border from the statusbar: `self.statusbar().setStyleSheet("QStatusBar::item{ border: 0px solid black };")` does the trick. It is important to `setStyleSheet` only on the `statusbar` object and not the entire application.