# PyQt5 Statusbar gets hidden when hovering over Menu item

Tags: python-2.7, menu, pyqt, pyqt5, statusbar

I´m trying to learn PyQt5 through a tutorial. I´m using Python 2.7 and PyQt5.

This code should create a menubar with a "View" entry. Inside the "View" entry you should be able to check or uncheck an option to show or hide the statusbar below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example,self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):         

        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Ready')

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        viewMenu = menubar.addMenu('View')
        viewMenu.menuAction().setStatusTip("File Menu is hovered")

        self.myMessage = QLabel()
        self.myMessage.setText("Hello")

        self.statusbar.addPermanentWidget(self.myMessage)

        viewStatAct = QAction('View statusbar', self, checkable=True)
        #viewStatAct.setStatusTip('View statusbar')
        viewStatAct.setChecked(True)
        viewStatAct.triggered.connect(self.toggleMenu)

        viewMenu.addAction(viewStatAct)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Check menu')    
        self.show()

    def toggleMenu(self, state):

        if state:
            self.statusBar().show()
        else:
            self.statusBar().hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=0
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that, however, when I move the mouse over the "View" entry the statusbar disappears completely and doesnt react to any clicks on the menubar like it is supposed to do.

I have looked at other tutorials, questions in SO and the documentation page to no avail.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QStatusBar message disappears on menu hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695200/qstatusbar-message-disappears-on-menu-hover)

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited my code to show that the suggested answers didnt work for me

Comment: @Iridium. I all works exactly as expected for me. What platform are you testing this on?

Comment: Win7 64 bit, Jupyter Notebook with Python 2.7.14 64bit and PyQt5.6.0. This is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always want some default status text displayed, adding the following method to your class should do the trick.

```
def event(self, e):
    if e.type() == QtCore.QEvent.StatusTip:
        if e.tip() == '':
            e = QtGui.QStatusTipEvent('Ready')  # Set this to whatever you like
    return super().event(e)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That totally worked. One small remark though if someone looks this question up: this answer works as is on Python 3.X, for Python 2.X you have to include `Example,self` inside `return super().event(e)`